# Generator of cyclic groups $Z_{pq} $

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Instead of asking to find the number of generators of $Z_{pq} $ where $p$ and $q$ are prime numbers it was asked to find generators of $Z_{pq}$.
This is to find the number s which are relatively prime to $pq$.
Is there any method to find all numbers relatively prime to $pq$ ? 
I know $1,p, q$ and $(pq-1)$ will be relatively prime to $pq $ .But these are not the only numbers relatively primer to $pq$ . All multiples of $p$ and $q$ less than $pq $ will not be relatively prime to $pq$ . but it is not enough
Can we generalise this question ? that means can we find all numbers less than a particular number $n$ and relatively prime to $n$.

Comment: look up Euler's totient function.

Comment: Euler's totient function gives number of numbers relatively prime to n But I need all these numbers..How?

Comment: it's a start. There is no simple formula to generate all such numbers. If you would look at the Euler totient function you'll see just figuring out its value is not trivial.

Comment: You wrote that each of $p$ and $q$ is relatively prime to $pq$. (Sentence #4.)

Comment: thanks $p$ and $q$ are not relatively prime to $pq $but what about $p-1 $and $q-1$